# Cannot set a specific value to a choice field

Tags: 2013, 2010, list, choice-field, internal-server-error

My problem is very strange.

In a SharePoint server 2013 site collection with user experience 2010. The choice field is set to "`allow fill-in choices`".

**The problem is that** we can't "**specify your own value**". the field is grey like disable.

I can't know where this problem comes from. Has somebody an idea? thanks

Comment: Have you tried in different browser and from different machines?

Comment: Yes. the problem is the same ..

Comment: We are experiencing this same issue in our 2013 Farm with 2010 compatibility mode. This happened when we upgraded to SharePoint 2013 June 2016 CU. Before that we were at February or April 2016. Testing with the 15 Hive form.js file fixed it, but then broke attaching files to list items. Working with MS on this now.

Answer (score 1):

Viewing with console development browser, I find the **source problem** :

```
 SetDisabledOnControl function is unknown.
```

This [post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ef75f56b-13cf-4e97-a81f-6e8869ffb4c6/sharepoint-choice-field-specify-your-own-value?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) indicates **the source problem is an UC update**. 
But I can't test the proposition on this post to validate it.

I think it's dangerous to edit a `forms.js` file on a PROD server.

**The solution** is to upgrade this site collection to user experience 2013.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the user with whom you try to add value to choice field is having "***Contribute***" **access** on the list/library in which this field has been added.

Comment: I tried with full-control permissions without success