# SharePoint Choice Column, unable to specify fill-in choice

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, custom-list

We've been asked to take a look at a customer's SharePoint.

SharePoint Setup Details:

- SharePoint Foundation 2013
- Single Server Install Quad Core, 12GB RAM.
- Machine is shared with another mission critical application.
- Installed version is 2013 RTM Build
- SP1 is installed but they have not run the post update config.

We're looking bring the server more up to date, however they've asked us to look at one issue before we do that as it is impeding some work.

They have a Custom List with a Choice column that allows fill-in answers. However there is no input on the form for "Specify Your Own Value". The drop down is there with the pre-populated choices and can be selected. The form is just the OOTB form, no customisation. If you select the radio button for "Specify Your Own Value" It throws the JS Error:

```
SetDisabledOnControl is null or undefined
```

A similar thread [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/186985/cannot-set-a-specific-value-to-a-choice-field/187156#187156) talks about the issue but our customer is not using the 2010 user experience, they are already using 2013 experience so I cannot upgrade it as they have suggested here. They also mentioned that the bug was introduced by a May/June 2016 CU, which hasn't been installed on this server.

Has anyone come across this in 2013 User Experience? Would patching the server as planned be the way to resolve this?

Edit:

So in the mean time I have discovered a work around for this. Instead of editing the individual item on the list, we were able to click the "Edit this List" at the top of the All Items View, scroll to the item we wanted to edit and fill-in the option into the choice column that way. It saved but the item on the new/edit form still gives the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We encountered a similar issue. this [link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/ef75f56b-13cf-4e97-a81f-6e8869ffb4c6/sharepoint-choice-field-specify-your-own-value?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious) provided a solution for a different scenario. But it turned out our hive 15 form.js file did not have the SetDisabledOnControl function at all. I added it right after the SetFocusOnControl function and rebooted the front ends (an IISRESET probably would have worked as well, but needed to reboot the servers anyway).

Here is the code for the missing function.

```
function SetDisabledOnControl(b,c){a:;var a=document.getElementById(b);if(a!=null)if(c)a.setAttribute("disabled","true");else a.removeAttribute("disabled")}
```